# Typescript interface for array object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am currently accepting interface for my component and it accept the array object "options" as one of its arguments. My question is how do you create an interface for array object. I believe you need to use index signature for the interface but I havent used it before and not sure how it need to be strcuture.

[image]

Currently I uses arrow function. And here is how I declare my interface of my function

```
   interface IOption {
         key: number;
        text: string;
        value: number
    }
    Interface DropDownInputInt {
              name: string;
              value: any;
              label: string;
              disabled: boolean;
              onChange: Function;
              extraClassName: string;
              required: boolean;
              options: IOption[] | string;
              multiple: boolean;
              clearable: boolean;
              index?: number;
              placeholder: string;
              toolTipMessage: string;
              addCollon: boolean;
}

const DropDownInput = ({
              name,
              value,
              label,
              disabled,
              onChange,
              extraClassName,
              required,
              options,
              multiple,
              clearable,
              index,
              placeholder,
              toolTipMessage,
              addCollon
}: DropDownInputInt) => {
            //MY CODES HERE
})
```

My second question is how do you create in interface that accept both string and object.

Comment: Could you clarify what is the question? Array of objects would be `Array<IOption>` or `IOption[]` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
interface IOption {
  key: number;
  text: string;
  value: number; // or any
}

function func(options: IOption[]) {}
```

> but if you are accepting other arguments how do you declare it on interface? I hope there is a way without declaring everything inline

I am not quite familiar with React.js, but normally you should be able to do it with TypeScript anyway

```
interface DropDownInputInt {
  name: string;
  value: any;
  label: string;
  // bla bla ...
}


const DropDownInput = (dropdownOptions: DropDownInputInt) => {
  // your code here
}
```

As for your other question

> My second question is how do you create in interface that accept both string and object.

Here is an example (see the pipe `|`):

```
interface DropDownInputInt {
  somethindThatAcceptsBothStringAndObject: string | object
  // bla bla ...
}
```

> I tried to incorporate your answer in my code, see my change above but somehow it throws error inside the body of my function saying "Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string | IOption'. when I tried drilling down the options.value

Ok, so as per your `DropDownInputInt` interface, you accept `string` and `IOption[]` types for the `options` property. Since you have two different types, you should check the `options` type like so:

```
const DropDownInput = (dropdownOptions: DropDownInputInt) => {
  // ...
  if(typeof dropdownOptions.options === 'string') {
    // you have a string here
  } else if(Array.isArray(dropdownOptions.options) && dropdownOptions.options.length > 0) {
    // you have IOption array here, which is not empty
    dropdownOptions.options[0].value; // accessing the value of the first option
    dropdownOptions.options[1].value; // accessing the value of the second option
    // etc. or simply use a for-loop to evaluate the options
  }
}
```

Comment: but if you are accepting other arguments how do you declare it on interface? I hope there is a way without declaring everything inline

Comment: @Billy Updated my answer.

Comment: I tried to incorporate your answer in my code, see my change above but somehow it throws error inside the body of my function saying "Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string | IOption'. when I tried drilling down the options.value

Comment: @Billy do you mean  "Property 'value' does not exist on type `string | IOption[]` or is it really `string | IOption`? Cause, in your `DropDownInputInt` you have `string | IOption[]`